How to flip a static QMap to another static QMap in C++ Qt 6?
I need to map a set of string values to an enum type and back.
In my header file I have:
const static QMap<aMessage::Type, QString> type2str;
const static QMap<QString, aMessage::Type> str2type;

And in the corresponding source file type2str gets initialized OOL with an init-list:
const static QMap<aMessage::Type, QString> type2str
{
    {aMessage::Type::Connect, "connect"},
    {aMessage::Type::Message, "message"},
    {aMessage::Type::Name, "name"},
    {aMessage::Type::Disconnect, "disconnect"},
};

How should I initialize the inverse of type2str into str2type without copy-paste?

Iterate over type2str and str2type[val] = key? Or what do you mean by "without copy-paste"? The copy of keys and values needs to be made, because you have 2 maps.

Is it really worth the performance to store it 2 times? Why not searching in values for the correct key? You could implement a a container that holds 2 maps, where you can access with each key the corresponding other key and vice versa

That sounds like Guava's table, QMap and Qt general containers are illsuited for that

Wouldn't the enum -> string be handled better with a good old static array?  Then, the other direction can be a map.

If you want to have 2 QMaps Enum->String and String->Enum, you can simply initialize the second map by iterating over the first one:
const static QMap<QString, MsgType> str2type = []() {
    QMap<QString, aMessage::Type> result;
    for (auto it = type2str.keyValueBegin(); it != type2str.keyValueEnd(); ++it) {
        result[it->second] = it->first;
    }
    return result;
}();

Note however that all the keys and values are copied from first map to the other map. If you want to avoid making copies and have a single container, you could use e.g. boost bimap that allows you to do the lookup using first or second element of the map. The example with English<->Spanish dictionary seems to be exactly your case.
